# Convert the unicode to datetime format

Tags: python, datetime, unicode

A function returns date and time in unicode format.

```
 u'2014-03-06T04:38:51Z'
```

I wish to convert this to date and time format and subtract it with current datetime to get the number of days in between.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what-have-u-tried.com ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: The current datetime is `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 4):

Check string is **unicode**

```
>>> import types
>>> type(u'2014-03-06T04:38:51Z') is types.UnicodeType
True
```

Converting **strings** to **datetime**:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(u'2014-03-06T04:38:51Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 6, 4, 38, 51)
```

**Subtract** from **today** to

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> yourdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(u'2014-03-06T04:38:51Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
>>> difference = today - yourdate
print str(difference)
```

Answer (score 3):

First you have to convert your string to a `datetime.datetime` object.

```
import datetime
then = datetime.datetime.strptime(u'2014-03-06T04:38:51Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

`then` represents itself as `datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 6, 4, 38, 51)`, which looks about right. Then you have to get today's date as a `datetime.datetime`.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Finally subtract it from your date (or *vice versa* - the question didn't make it clear).`delta` is a `datetime.timedelta` object that stores increments in days, seconds and microseconds. The latter two are always positive, the first can be negative.

```
for delta in (now-then, then-now):
    print(delta, "::", delta.days, delta.seconds, delta.microseconds)
```

This prints out:

```
-1 day, 20:18:14.250142 :: -1 73094 250142
3:41:45.749858 :: 0 13305 749858
```

Best try it with a few examples to convince yourself it's correct.

Comment: fiinally i solved my problem and then i see this. anyways thanks steve

Comment: Always do the research first! Glad you solved your problem